# How to solve the problem of CSRF regenerate token in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a view page where I have added a form having csrf token. Whenever I try to submit the form, the form gets submitted sometimes and sometime it shows error "The action you have requested is not allowed.". How to get rid of this error and enable the user to submit the form as many times as he can?

config.php

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'abhisuskart_stan';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'abhistan_cook';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
```

View page

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('user/signup');?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="redirecturl" value="<?php echo $redirecto;?>">
                          <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btnsignup">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you updating the form with the new csrf token each time it's submitted? If not then set csrf_generate to false.

Comment: If I need to update the form each time after submission, then what shall I have to do sir?